# How to convert dataframe to 1D array ?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

First of all apologies. I am very new to pandas, scikit learn and python. So I am sure I am doing something silly. Let me give a little background.

I am trying to run KNeighborsClassifier from scikit learn (python)
Following is my strategy

```
#Reading the Training set
data = pd.read_csv('Path_TO_File\\Train_Set.csv', sep=',') # reading CSV File
X = data[['Attribute 1','Attribute 2']] 
y = data['Target_Column'] # the output is a Dataframe of single column with many rows
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
neigh.fit(X,y)
```

Next I try to read Test data

```
test = pd.read_csv('PATH_TO_FILE\\Test.csv', sep=',')
t = test[['Attribute 1','Attribute 2']] 
pred = neigh.predict(t)
actual = test['Target_Column']
```

Next I try to check the accuracy by following function which is throwing error.

```
accuracy=neigh.score(actual,pred)
```

ERROR: ValueError: could not convert string to float: N

I checked actual and pred both and they are of following data type and content

```
actual
Out[161]: 
    Target_Column
0             Y
1             N
:

[614 rows x 1 columns]

pred
Out[162]: 
array(['Y', 'N', .....'N'], dtype=object)
```

N.B : pred has 614 values.

I tried to convert "actual" variable to 1D array I might be able to execute the function however, I am not successful.

I think I need to do following two things, however, was not able to do so (after googling it)

1) Convert actual into 1Dimen array
2) Making a transpose of the 1Dimen array since the pred has 614 columns.

Please let me know how to correct the function.

Thanks in advance !
Raj

Comment: No, you have to convert Y and N to 1 and 0

Comment: Please note: I also tried neigh.score(y,actual) but getting following error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: N

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vivek and Thornhale

Indeed I was doing two wrong things.

1. As pointed by you guys, I should have been using 1, 0 in stead of Y,
   N.
2. I was giving wrong parameters to the function score. It should be
   accuracy=neigh.score(t, actual) , where t is test feature set and
   actual is test label information.

Answer (score -1):

You could convert your series which is what you get when you do "test[COLUMN_NAME]" into an array like so:

```
actual = np.array(test['Target_Column'])
```

To then reshape an np array, you would emply this command:

```
actual.reshape(1, 612) # <- Could be the other way around as well.
```

Your main issue though is that your Series needs to be boolean (as in 0,1).